# ASP.NET Core DI access container directly

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there a way of accessing the DI container of ASP.NET Core directly from a class?

Usually what is done is constructor injection:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    public ProductsController(ISomeService service)
    {

    }
}
```

Instead, I would like to do something like:

```
var service = ServiceLocator.GetService<ISomeService>();
```

For some services I would not like to use the default constructor injection, but rather get the service directly from the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called the *Service locator pattern* and can be done by injecting the IServiceProvider

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    public ProductsController(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        var service = services.GetService<ISomeService>(); 
    }
}
```

[Here's](https://medium.com/volosoft/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-best-practices-tips-tricks-c6e9c67f9d96) a good article which goes throw the different strategies

Comment: yes, but what if you can't use injection. I have a background task scheduler and it doesn't support DI, so I have to crate the services manually ... any ideas ?